# Does c++ have an equivalent to Typescripts' intersection type?

Tags: c++, c++17

I came back to c++ after some time with Typescript and learnt that in Typescript we could do something like this:

```
let ojbect: InterfaceA & InterfaceB = new InterfaceAandBImplementation();
```

It's called an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). I wanted to do the same in C++, using pure virtual classes as interfaces, but I can't seem to get the same done... and it's getting quite annoying. Apparently, Java support it as well in generics - as far as I know - so it's not a TS-only.

### Specific use case

I have `Light` and `Camera` classes for my OpenGL application and wanted to attach instances of them to world objects.

```cpp
class Camera
    : public Interface::Positionable
    , public Interface::Directionable
{ ... }

class Light
{ ... }

class SpotLight
    : public Light
    , public Interface::Positionable
    , public Interface::Directionable
{ ... }
```

These are the interfaces:

```cpp
namespace Interface
{
    class Positionable
    {
    public:
        virtual const glm::vec3& getPosition() const = 0;

        virtual void addToPosition(const glm::vec3& position) = 0;

        virtual void setPosition(const glm::vec3& position) = 0;
    };

    class Directionable
    {
    public:
        virtual const glm::vec3& getDirection() const = 0;

        virtual void addToDirection(const glm::vec3& direction) = 0;

        virtual void setDirection(const glm::vec3& direction) = 0;
    };
}
```

With the `FixedAttachment` class I wanted to follow objects with cameras, but attach spot lights (head lights to spaceships for example) with this class as well.

```cpp
class FixedAttachment
{
public:
    FixedAttachment(std::shared_ptr<Interface::Positionable> target, std::shared_ptr<Interface::Directionable> tracker, const glm::vec3& position)
        : Attachment{ target },
        m_tracker{ tracker },
        m_position{ position }
    {
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Interface::Positionable> getSharedTarget() const { return m_target; }
    Interface::Positionable* getTarget() const { return m_target.get(); }
    const glm::vec3& getPosition() const { return m_position; }

    void updateTracker()
    {
        /* Calculate new direction, position here for the tracker based upon target */
        // m_tracker->setDirection(calculatedDirection);
        // m_tracker->setPosition(calculatedPosition);
        // ^^^^^^^^^ impossible, not a positionable yet
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Interface::Positionable> m_target;
    std::shared_ptr<Interface::Directionable> m_tracker;
    glm::vec3 m_position;
};
```

As pointed out by the code-comment in `updateTracker`, I need `m_tracker` to be a `Interface::Positionable` as well.

So what I really want is just to store my `m_tracker` like:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Interface::Positionable & Interface::Directionable> m_tracker;
```

(And modify constructor etc.) I could solve this by creating an interface class that combines the other 2:

```cpp
class PosDirIntersection
    : public Interface::Positionable,
    : public Interface::Directionable
{}
```

But that's just avoiding the problem, because then I would have to Derive Camera and SpotLight from it as well to be able to pass it. If I then would create a function that accepts a variable of type `LightDirIntersection` (`Light & Interface::Directionable`), I would no longer be able to pass it a variable of type `SpotLight`. Plus, it forces me to modify classes just to pass it somewhere outside their definition, which is why I don't like this solution.

So far I haven't found any solution to this problem. Is there any?

Comment: For static polymorphism using templates, you have C++20 _Concepts_, where you can compose different concepts/constraints.

Comment: You can `SpotLight` to a function accepting `LightDirIntersection` if you template the function and are willing to upgrade to `C++20` with concepts. `template <class T> requires std::derived_from<T,BaseClassA> && std::derived_from<T, baseClassB>`. Read more: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: If `SpotLight` inherits from `PosDirIntersection`, it is a `Directionable`, so you could pass it as one. I don't understand what the problem is. Both `Camera` and `SpotLight` both inherits from `Directional` and `Positional` already.

Comment: @super I think the issue is that it needs to pass it as both `Directional` and `Positional`, which wouldn't work with standard polymorphism

Comment: @Lala5th It does. If you just combine the interfaces as shown in the question.

Comment: Note that `Positionable` and `Directional` should both have virtual destructors

Comment: @Lala5th, yes indeed, I want to have a member that is both `Directional` and `Positional`

Comment: @Bob And you can do that with `PosDirIntersection`. The question of why that doesn't work for you is still unclear. Especially as your reasoning of not being able to pass it as a `Directionable` is wrong.

Comment: @super, I *could*, just like the alternative solution in the question states, but then I have to make any type I want to store there that implements both a `Directional` and a `Positionable` a `PosDirIntersection` instead, which is what I didn't want. If I'm not mistaken it's impossible to store `Camera` for example without being it an explicit `PosDirIntersection`.

Comment: @Bob Yes. What your question doesn't say is *why*. `Camera` is already both a `Directional` and `Positional`. So making it a `PosDirIntersection` wouldn't make any difference to the rest of your code.

Comment: @super Making it `PosDirIntersection` wouldn't make a difference, but what if you have 3 of these base classes you'd need 3, combinations of each pairs. 4 and you need 6, 5 -> 10 and so on. It is not something you want to write nor read.

Comment: @super, I disagree, as stated, I would have to create another interface `LightDirIntersection` and derive SpotLight from that as well if I wanted to use a `LightDirIntersection`, which results in having duplicate inheritance from SpotLight of Direction (`LightDirIntersection`, `PosDirIntersection`). I had assumed I would have a [diamond problem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem ). Now I understand that I problably will not, since my methods are `=0`... Though the other problem remains: I'm modifying finished code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In typescript, `type C = A & B` is basically a way to cheat your way to get `interface C extends A, B {}`.

What this does is simply merge the members from left to right. If that is what you desire then `class C : A, B {}` is probably the closest.

Otherwise, for type requirements in functions you will need concepts (or a [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) equivalent but that will get messy really quick) :

```cpp
template <class T>
concept Positionable = requires(T obj){
  { std::is_base_of_v<Interface::Positionable, T> }
}


template <class T>
concept Directionable = requires(T obj){
  { std::is_base_of_v<Interface::Directionable, T> }
}
```

Then you could make any combination of concepts and require them in your functions :

```cpp
void doStuff(Directionable auto direct){}
void doOtherStuff(Positionable auto direct){}
```

On a sidenote, what you seem to need feels a lot like the [Entity Component System pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). In which case, [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) is a good implementation. You could also write your own for more specific needs and smaller footprint.

Comment: You specifically mention Concepts for functions. It doesn't solve the problem of storing a member of type `C`? I will assume I'll have to stick with `class C : A, B {}` then.

Comment: C++ does not support intersection in types, the best you'll have for that is multiple inheritance and targeting that.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I shall accept my own solution then :p (I'm also checking out EnTT, thanks for that!)

Comment: I think ECS will be what fits your needs. It goes around your problem by using composition and knowing what each entity stores